# How to Show Dates on x Axis ggplot in R Programming Language?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I have this data file:

```
       Time      Area  Height
1 2/26/2000 484226449 1560.46
2  3/5/2000 475053975 1560.42
3 3/13/2000 466963590 1560.39
4 3/21/2000 441697246 1560.29
5 3/29/2000 428258729 1560.25
6  4/6/2000 408551641 1560.16
```

The `ggplot` shows chart but date ranges doesn't show on xAxis:

```
ggplot(t2, aes(x = Time, y = Area, group = 1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KC5b.jpg)

Comment: Try with converting to date format before plotting, i.e. `t2$Time <- as.Date(t2$Time, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add the data sample so that we can reproduce it on our systems with `dput()`? My first impulse would have been Stefans suggestion. If it's not that, it is really hard to guess the problem without a closer look at the data types and structure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. First convert your `Time`variable to date format. Second. Depending on your desired format you can set the number of breaks and the format for the labels via `scale_x_date`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

t2 <- read.table(text = "Time      Area  Height
1 2/26/2000 484226449 1560.46
2  3/5/2000 475053975 1560.42
3 3/13/2000 466963590 1560.39
4 3/21/2000 441697246 1560.29
5 3/29/2000 428258729 1560.25
6  4/6/2000 408551641 1560.16", header = TRUE)

t2$Time <- as.Date(t2$Time, "%m/%d/%Y")
ggplot(t2, aes(x = Time, y = Area)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d %b %Y")
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that date_labels seems to format to local language. How cool is that.